# Limited shape as output in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to randomly generate timeseries data using keras as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import pandas as pd
import random
input_data = [random.uniform(10,100) for _ in range(350000)]
targets = [random.uniform(10,100) for _ in range(350000)]
dataset = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    input_data, targets, sequence_length=10000)
for batch in dataset:
  inputs, targets = batch
  break
```

But the final shape is reduced and coming as:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(128, 10000), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[22.922523, 44.253967, 41.80049 , ..., 60.444836, 14.977458,
        17.970036],
       [44.253967, 41.80049 , 34.09485 , ..., 14.977458, 17.970036,
        68.27751 ],
       [41.80049 , 34.09485 , 37.27845 , ..., 17.970036, 68.27751 ,
        98.05703 ],
       ...,
       [13.941159, 51.48634 , 61.248505, ..., 98.093346, 67.3885  ,
        34.01148 ],
       [51.48634 , 61.248505, 77.34204 , ..., 67.3885  , 34.01148 ,
        27.165142],
       [61.248505, 77.34204 , 54.856853, ..., 34.01148 , 27.165142,
        97.55085 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

How can i increase size array or is there any limitation?

Comment: The default batch size of `tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array` is 128. Each batch consists of 128 sequences and each sequence has 10000 timesteps. There is nothing wrong here.

Answer (score -1):

change the `VARIABLE` with the number of sample that you want (batch_size).
If you want the whole data you can make `batch_size=None`

```
dataset = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
input_data, targets, batch_size=VARIABLE, sequence_length=10000)
```